# No puedo hacer SELECT luego de haber insertado en una misma variable php filas nuevas a la tabla

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Como pueden ver, tengo una variable llamada $sql, la cual contiene dos instrucciones iguales. Las hace bien, el tema es cuando hago el  SELECT abajo, no me muestra nada, me genera este mensaje de error: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in.
Pero cuando dejo solo un INSERT en la variable $sql, el SELECT funciona bien y mee imprime la lista. Que puede ser?
Gracias

````
$sql = "INSERT INTO informacion (artista, album) VALUES ('$artista','$album'); INSERT INTO informacion (artista, album) VALUES ('$artista','$album');";

            echo '<br><br>' . $sql . '<br><br>';

            if ($conexion->multi_query($sql)) {

                echo '<br>Se registró el álbum.';

                //PARA SELECCIONAR ELEMENTOS DE LA TABLA Y PODER IMPRIMIRLOS PARA QUE EL USUARIO LOS VEA:

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM informacion WHERE 1 = 1;";

                echo '<br><br>' . $sql . '<br><br>';

                $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

                echo '<br><br><br>';

                    if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {

                        while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {

                            echo $row['id'] . ' ';
                            echo $row['artista'] . ' ';
                            echo $row['album'];
                            echo '<br><br>';            

                        }

                    } else {
                        echo '<br><br>No hay';
                    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Por lo visto, el método multi_query() no puede usarse así sin más. Debes gestionar todas las queries una por una. Concretamente, deberías llamar al método `next_result()` por cada instrucción. Podrías solucionarlo así:

```
if ($conexion->multi_query($sql)) {
         echo '<br>Se registró el álbum.';

         do
         {
            // haz algo aquí si te interesa, como comprobar errores, etc.
         }
         while ($conexion->next_result());

         ...
    }
```